# Tools for Latency Test?

Tags: jmeter, latency, response-time

I want to do a latency test for my web aplication. My applcation is using a 3 tier achitecture, a web server , an app server and a DB server. The web server is mainly configured for loadbalancing and static images , css and js will be served by web server. I want to measure the latency for web server app server and for DB erver. Is there any good ool for measuring this. I need to get a graph for the latency. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use a mixture of a front end load testing tool like JMeter together with a back end application performance monitoring tool like new relic.

New Relic's graphing capabilities are great.

JMeter's graphing capabilities aren't very good so a JMeter as a service solution like BlazeMeter can provide nice latency graphs.